# Get Dynamically Loaded HTML After Scrolling To Bottom

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriver;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Settings;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Timezone; 

public class ReadMovies {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().timezone(Timezone.AMERICA_NEWYORK).build());
        driver.get("http://www.cinesift.com/#/");

        driver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");

        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

However, the `executeScript()` seems to be having no effect - the program still prints the original source as when the page was first loaded (so no additional elements were loaded). Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are additional movies loaded when you scroll the page down. If you want to load all of the or certain amount of movies, you would have to continuously scroll down and wait.

Naive implementation:

```
int DESIRED_COUNT = 100;
int currentCount = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#films .film")).size();

while (currentCount < DESIRED_COUNT) {
    driver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    currentCount = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#films .film")).size();
}

// now get the page source
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

The `Thread.sleep()` wait should probably be replaced with an Explicit Wait via `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: The Thread.sleep() was the part I was missing. Didn't realize that I actually need to give the server time to respond :). Thanks!

Comment: @JohnRoberts `Thread.sleep()` should generally speaking be avoided and a `WebDriverWait()` should be used instead. Though, for this task, I think it's pretty much okay - we sort of have an expected condition check in the while loop condition.